# Looking for multiple strings in variable stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a stored procedure for cloned databases. I want to check the database_name variable for a specific string. Currently, this is what I've got:

```
IF ((CONTAINS(:database_name, 'STRING1'))=TRUE) THEN
        RAISE clone_exception;
END IF;

    IF ((CONTAINS(:database_name, 'STRING2'))=TRUE) THEN
        RAISE clone_exception;
END IF;

IF ((CONTAINS(:database_name, 'STRING3'))=TRUE) THEN
        RAISE clone_exception;
END IF;
```

I don't want to have to write 3 CONTAIN blocks I'd rather keep it compact and clean, is there a way I could get all 3 STRING checks in the same block of code? I've looked into using the IN operator but I can't find documentation that doesn't have examples using only a table query which doesn't really help me since this conditional is comparing only a variable and not a table column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to achieve with [LIKE ANY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like_any.html):

```
DECLARE 
    database_name TEXT := '...';
BEGIN
   IF (:database_name ILIKE ANY ('%STRING1%','%STRING2%','%STRING3%') THEN
    RAISE clone_exception:
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the answer! I tried it and it didn't work at first but then I added the % into the string and it worked so thank you for that! Just a quick question, is there no way to do this using the IN operator? Just curious

Comment: @Justine Yes, but `IN`  is an **exact match**: `IF (:database_name IN ('STRING1', 'STRING2',...) THEN...` ILIKE ANY emulates CONTAINS.